# How facebook/other sites know what I browsed?

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, session-cookies, ads

I see that Facebook comes up with relevant Ads just moments after I visited a travel site or a e-commerce site. How does this work?

Do these sites drop cookies and allow Social sites to read them? Is it even possible to share cookies across domains?

Is there some server-server communication happening where each of these partners will share some details with each other as what a user at a particular IP is doing?

I really want to understand the technology concepts behind "targeted Ads using browsing history" (definitely not a homework topic. Been out of college almost 6 years ago :))

Answer (score 2):

It's called re-targeting and uses third-party cookies.

When you visit Website A, a script on their site sends a message to Ad Broker (the 'third party') with details to identify you and which products your have browsed.

Then, when you later visit Website B (who also has a script provided by Ad Broker) they send a message with your identification and request any relevant ads.

If Ad Broker has your details on file, they will provide relevant ads based on your browsing history, otherwise they will send back generic ads, or ads based on the content of the page your are viewing on Website B.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_retargeting